# Is it possible to show an alternative menu when holding "Alt" on an opened context menu in Electron?

Tags: electron

On macOS, when right-clicking on a file, then holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>, it does show more advanced options. Is it possible to reproduce it using Electron? Thank you!